# Removing elements from a nested list based on their global count

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a very large table containing sublists, such as for instance:

```
{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6, 7}, {1}, {1, 8}, {9, 10}, {11, 6, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16}}
```

I want to remove elements from all sublists based on their count. For example, from the list above I would like to remove all elements of count greater than or equal to 2. In this case only 1 and 6 appear more than twice, so those should be removed, and I would like the following output:

```
{{2, 3}, {4, 5, 7}, {8}, {9, 10}, {11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16}}
```

Comment: This does not remove the 1's and 6's inside the sublist

Comment: How dense is the list, that is, is the expectation of duplicate/triplicate/etc. high or low? Depending on this, methods posted so far can be handily beaten. And what is "very large"? Millions of sublists, or thousands? Different techniques for each case...

Comment: What would be the bottleneck, @ciao, tallying, the selecting, or the delete cases?

Comment: @march: I'd venture the selecting - but when/if OP more precisely specifies, I'll enter the fray with ideas if appropriate. As it stands, too under-specified to guide fastest solution, IMO.

Answer (score 7):

Version 10 offers `Counts` which is useful for this question:

```
$list = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6, 7}, {1}, {1, 8}, {9, 10}, {11, 6, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16}};

count = Counts @ Flatten @ $list

(* <| 1->3, 2->1, 3->1, 4->1, 5->1, 6->2, 7->1, 8->1, 9->1, 10->1, 11->1,
      12->1, 13->1, 14->1, 15->1, 16->1 |> *)

count[6]

(* 2 *)
```

(A shame that `Counts` does not accept a level specification.)

With this information, we can use `DeleteCases` to express the requirement fairly directly:

```
DeleteCases[$list, x_ /; count[x] >= 2, {2}]

(* {{2, 3}, {4, 5, 7}, {}, {8}, {9, 10}, {11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16}} *)
```

Or we could use `Pick` to keep the desired values:

```
Pick[$list, Map[count[#] < 2 &, $list, {2}]]

(* {{2, 3}, {4, 5, 7}, {}, {8}, {9, 10}, {11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16}} *)
```

With version 10.2, we can replace all rejected values with `Nothing`:

```
$list /. x_Integer /; count[x] >= 2 -> Nothing

(* {{2, 3}, {4, 5, 7}, {}, {8}, {9, 10}, {11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16}} *)
```

... although in earlier versions the cryptic `(##&[])` can express the idea of `Nothing`.

Each of these techniques leaves an empty sublist when all of its original elements are rejected.  We can use the operator `DeleteCases[{}]` to get rid of such empty remnants.  For example:

```
DeleteCases[$list, x_ /; count[x] >= 2, {2}] // DeleteCases[{}]

(* {{2, 3}, {4, 5, 7}, {8}, {9, 10}, {11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16}} *)
```

Comment: The pronunciation of `(##&[])` cannot be uttered in polite company.  It is a rather harsh colloquial synonym for `Nothing`.  ;)

Comment: Also it's impossible to search for it.

Comment: @shrx FWIW I use the term ["vanishing function"](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22vanishing+function%22)

Answer (score 6):

```
a = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6, 7}, {1}, {1, 8}, {9, 10}, {11, 6, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16}};

b = First /@ Select[Tally[Flatten@a], Last[#] > 1 &];

c = DeleteCases[a /. Thread[b -> Sequence[]], {}]
```

> {{2, 3}, {4, 5, 7}, {8}, {9, 10}, {11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16}}

Answer (score 5):

If

```
list = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6, 7}, {1}, {1, 8}, {9, 10}, {11, 6, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16}}
```

then define

```
outs = Alternatives @@ Cases[Tally@Flatten@list, a_ /; Last@a >= 2 :> First@a];
```

Change the `2` to whatever tally you want.

Then

```
DeleteCases[#, outs] & /@ list /. {} -> Sequence[]
(* {{2, 3}, {4, 5, 7}, {8}, {9, 10}, {11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16}} *)
```

Alternatively (based on a comment from `MarcoB`),

```
DeleteCases[list, outs, {2}] /. {} -> Sequence[]
```

Comment: As an alternative to `Map`ping the `DeleteCases` expression, you could also indicate a level specification for its application, such as `DeleteCases[list, outs, 2]`. (+1)

Comment: Yes that gets me what I wanted

Comment: @MarcoB. Thanks for the hint (+1); somehow I missed the fact that `Cases` takes a level-spec.

Comment: Slightly shorter version: `list /. Cases[Tally@Flatten@list, 
   a_ /; Last@a >= 2 :> (First@a -> Sequence[])] /. {} -> Sequence[]`

Comment: @march no problem, thank you for including it!

Answer (score 5):

My proposal, also leveraging [`Counts`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Counts.html) as used by WReach:

```
drop[expr_, thr_Integer] :=
  Pick[expr, Replace[expr, UnitStep[Counts[Join @@ expr] - thr], {2}], 0]
```

And not quite as efficient but pleasingly terse:

```
drop2[expr_, thr_Integer] :=
  Select[# < thr & /@ Counts[Join @@ expr]] /@ expr
```

Test:

```
input = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6, 7}, {1}, {1, 8}, {9, 10}, {11, 6, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16}};

drop[input, 2]
```

> ```
> {{2, 3}, {4, 5, 7}, {}, {8}, {9, 10}, {11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16}}
> ```

To drop the empty list you can follow with [`DeleteCases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteCases.html):

```
input ~drop~ 2 ~DeleteCases~ {}
```

> ```
> {{2, 3}, {4, 5, 7}, {8}, {9, 10}, {11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16}}
> ```

This appears to be somewhat faster than WReach's formulations.  His as functions:

```
WRf1[$list_, n_] :=
     With[{count = Counts@Flatten@$list},
      DeleteCases[$list, x_ /; count[x] >= n, {2}]
 ]

WRf2[$list_, n_] :=
     With[{count = Counts@Flatten@$list},
      Pick[$list, Map[count[#] < 2 &, $list, {2}]]
 ]

WRf3[$list_, n_] :=
     With[{count = Counts@Flatten@$list},
      $list /. x_Integer /; count[x] >= 2 :> Sequence[]
 ]
```

And a timing comparison:

```
big = RandomInteger[1*^5, {5000, 100}];

First @ RepeatedTiming @ #[big, 3] & /@ {WRf1, WRf2, WRf3, drop, drop2}
```

> ```
> {0.5712, 0.603, 0.593, 0.369, 0.434}
> ```

Answer (score 3):

```
test = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6, 7}, {1}, {1, 8}, {9, 10}, {11, 6, 12, 13,
    14, 15, 16}}
```

then

```
res=test /. Cases[
  Tally[Flatten@test], {x_, _?(# >= 2 &)} :> Rule[x, Sequence[]]]
```

yields:

```
{{2, 3}, {4, 5, 7}, {}, {8}, {9, 10}, {11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16}}
```

and

```
res/.{}->Sequence[]
```

will yield desired result